# Source code for Android MapView v2?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-mapview

I need to hack on **com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView**, but I can't seem to find the source. I already tried a Google search.

The reason I need to see the source is I want to know when it's done rendering. The MapView class extends FrameLayout, but the map itself is drawn with OpenGl so I really need to see where this is happening.

Comment: [There is some part of it on GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/google/android/maps/MapView.java) But I think the whole thing is not open sourced because it is part of the addon Google APIs, not the core OpenSourced android system.

Comment: Foamy's right. Google Maps is part of the proprietary side of things, and AFAIK none of the callbacks can tell you if the map has been loaded. At best [getMap()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView#getMap()) can tell you if there is a map or not.

Comment: Yeah, that's not good enough. I really, really need to know when it's done rendering the map.

Comment: Best thing you can do is add/star an issue on google code and hope it get's implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know when it's done rendering the map, this may help:
[GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback)

> Callback interface for when the map has finished rendering. This occurs after all tiles required to render the map have been fetched, and all labeling is complete. This event will not fire if the map never loads due to connectivity issues, or if the map is continuously changing and never completes loading due to the user constantly interacting with the map.